# msyql searching a domain, without the TLD extension

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search

How can we search for a domain, without the TLD in mysql, so for e.g. testdomain.com, I would want to search only `testdomain` not the `.com`, so a search for `test` would return row, but a search for `com` would not.

I assume it would be similar to below with some regex, but no idea how to achieve that.

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain_name LIKE '%$search%'
```

Any idea on how to to search just that part of the domain?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain_name LIKE '$search%'`. Removing the first `%` sign.

Comment: that will only search for anything starting with the keyword, e.g. if you search for `com` it will return something like `common.net`, but wouldnt return `test.com`, not would it return `testcom.org`

Comment: Will it work if you just search for the string in the part before the first `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM domains 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', 1) LIKE '%$search%'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for search a name starting with a string your query must be:

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain_name LIKE '$search%'
```

this query is a good query because it use indexes.

adding the "." character at the end you will find only the full name, 
also this query is a good query because it use indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain_name LIKE '$search.%'
```

Else if you want to make a partial search you need to add the % before and after the term but in this case the "com" search will match,  this search is not good becouse it do not use indexes.

At last this expressions search for a string containing the name excluding the TLD, this is not a good query because it do not use indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain_name LIKE '%$search%' and not like '%.$search%'
```

A good idea could be to split fields in your database, make a column (or an additional colunm) for the domain name without TLD and search in this new coloumn.